# How to send credentials to a powershell script in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

When executing the following code in a Jenkins pipeline, a "The following steps that have been detected may have insecure interpolation of sensitive variables" warning is being added to the build, with a link to https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation with explanation.

```
                powershell script: """ 
                \$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
                cd "${WORKSPACE}\\MyDirectory"
                & .\\myScript.ps1 -user "${creds_USR}" -passw "${creds_PSW}" 
            """
```

I've already tried to change it as described in the link above, but then the variables don't seem to be replaced anymore.

```
                powershell script: ''' 
                \$ErrorActionPreference = \"Stop\" 
                cd \"$WORKSPACE\\MyDirectory\"
                & .\\myScript.ps1 -user \"$creds_USR\" -passw \"$creds_PSW\" 
            '''
```

Would somebody know a working solution for this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you have a block like this that's generating those values:

```
environment {
    creds = credentials('some-credentials')
}
```

So your build environment has those variables available to Powershell. Rather than interpolating the string that constitutes the Powershell script, then, just write the script to pull the data from the environment.

```
    powershell script: '''\
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
cd "$Env:WORKSPACE\MyDirectory"
& .\myScript.ps1 -user "$Env:creds_USR" -passw "$Env:creds_PSW"
'''
```